# In Django views.py I create a session in method A and try to read it in class B. Error: attribute session not defined in class B

Tags: python, django, ajax, session, django-views

This may have a straigthforward solution. I hope you can help me.

I  submitted an Ajax Post to `methodA` in `views.py`. It works. I want to use the submitted variable as a session. I think it works as I'm able to print `request.session[]`. But now I want to read the session in a different class. See the following:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def methodA(request):
    myvariable=request.data['list'] # This is an Ajax Post
    request.session['myvar'] = myvariable # Creates session
    print(request.session['myvar']) # It works. shows Ajax Post value
    return JsonResponse({'success':True})

class classB(classC):

    def myvarmethod(request):
        print(request.session['myvar'])
    
    def importantmethod(self):
        self.myvarmethod()
        ...
        return [...] # some stuff
```

My goal is to print '`request.session['myvar']`' inside classB (in `importantmethod()`). The output is: object `classB` has not attribute `session`. Where do I need to define session? I have it well defined in `settings.py`. What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the `request` parameter from the `def myvarmethod(request):` since you are wanting to use the global variable. This is creating a new `request` variable with a local scope

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def methodA(request):
    myvariable=request.data['list'] # This is an Ajax Post
    request.session['myvar'] = myvariable # Creates session
    print(request.session['myvar']) # It works. shows Ajax Post value
    return JsonResponse({'success':True})

class classB(classC):

    def myvarmethod(self):
        print(self.request.session['myvar'])
    
    def importantmethod(self):
        self.myvarmethod()
        ...
        return [...] # some stuff
```